# Help to find the roots of an inverse trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry, roots, inverse-function, common-root

I'm looking forward to finding the roots in $x$ of the following function:

$$\frac{C^2}{\gamma}\arcsin\left(\frac{\gamma(x\sqrt{\beta}+(B-x)\sqrt{\alpha})}{C^2}\right)=x\sqrt{\alpha}-(x+B)\sqrt{\beta}-2(T-C)B$$

Where $C,\gamma,T$ and $C$ are constants and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are functions of $x$ given by $\alpha=C^2-\gamma^2x^2$ and $\beta=C^2-\gamma^2(B-x)^2$. Despite a large number of constants, does anyone have a hint of how I can proceed to find the roots of this function? I already know that depending on the constant values it has a real root for $x$. I'll be pleased with any kind of help :)

Comment: Avoid "hiding" the unknown in auxiliary variables, this makes reading more difficult. And simplify the constant expressions where possible.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but I'm not sure if I can simplify any constants at the moment and the auxiliary variables proved very useful in this case after some time working on it. I'll try to make it clearer next time

Comment: Can you share with us how you arrived at such an equation?

Comment: Well, its a long integration process:
$$\int_{0}^{B}{C\sqrt{1+f'(y)^2}-C+T+\gamma f(y)}dy$$
with $f(y)=(\sqrt{\beta}-\sqrt{C^2-\gamma^2(y-x)^2}$ and basically the variable $x$ that I used in the question is an integration constant. At the end of the day I want this expression to be positive for all the parameters so i need to find the roots for $x$...